# Update CSV File within Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I am currently working on the CSV files Create Editing and appending to CSV files the issue i am having is that i am trying to update to an existing CSV file but am running into trouble doing so.

When i run the code i am getting the following error.

```
/usr/bin/python3.5 /home/usr/PycharmProjects/csv/csv_file.py
2016-11-12 00:04:03.975247
2016-11-11 23:59:17.591426
MOD TIME IS Different
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/usr/PycharmProjects/csv/csv_file.py", line 157, in <module>
    Direcotry_function(sys.argv)
  File "/home/usr/PycharmProjects/csv/csv_file.py", line 133, in Direcotry_function
    for row in reader:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/csv.py", line 109, in __next__
    self.fieldnames
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/csv.py", line 96, in fieldnames
    self._fieldnames = next(self.reader)
_csv.Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Below is the Python Code which i can't seem to get working.

```
def function(dest):
    global directory_path #call the Global Variable
    directory_path =  os.getcwd() # getting Current Directory
    if len(dest) > 1:
        directory_path = dest
    for list in filepath_list:
        Originalfiles = ''.join(list)#Convert to Str
        drive, path = os.path.splitdrive(Originalfiles)#Get the Path
        path, filename = os.path.split(path)#Split the path and filename
        makedir = path + '/' + filename
        Originalfiles_Timestamp = os.path.getmtime(Originalfiles)#Get the Timestamp of File in seconds
        mTime = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(Originalfiles_Timestamp)#Get the Date time in Month Yearformat
        print(mTime)
        if os.path.exists(os.path.join(directory_path, filename[:]+".copy")):#Check if the FIle exists
            file_csv = csv.DictReader(open('datetime.csv'))#open CSV FILE
            for row in file_csv:#Loop over
                if row['FileName'] == Originalfiles:
                    rowTime =  datetime.datetime.strptime(row['ModificationDate'], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f") #Convert row to DateTime
                    print(rowTime)
                    if rowTime == mTime: #Check if Time inside CSV equals mTime
                        print("DATE IS THE SAME")
                        exit(1)
                    else:#if not equaled
                        print("MOD TIME IS Different")
                        global CSV_FILENAME
                        temp_file = NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)
                        with open(CSV_FILENAME, "rb") as f, temp_file:
                            reader = csv.DictReader(f)
                            fieldnames = ['FileName', 'ModificationDate']  # Create Dict Keys
                            writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=fieldnames)
                            for row in reader:
                                print(row)
                                writer.writerow({"FileName": row['FileName'], "ModificationDate": mTime})
                            shutil(temp_file.name, CSV_FILENAME)
                        os.system('cp -rv ' + makedir + ' ' + directory_path + '/' + filename[:] + ".copy")

                else:
                    with open('datetime.csv', 'a+') as f:
                        fieldnames = ['FileName', 'ModificationDate']
                        writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=fieldnames)
                        writer.writeheader()#WRITE KEYS
                        writer.writerow({'FileName': Originalfiles, 'ModificationDate': mTime})#WRITE Values

        else:
            #If Copy File Does not Exists in the Folder do the Following:
            os.system('cp -r ' + makedir + ' ' + directory_path + '/' + filename[:]+".copy")#Copy ther File to the Directory
            with open('datetime.csv', 'a+') as csvfile:#Open CSV File
                fieldnames = ['FileName', 'ModificationDate']#Create Dict Keys
                writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
                writer.writeheader()
                writer.writerow({'FileName': Originalfiles, 'ModificationDate': mTime})#Write to The CSV File
```

EDIT:

So after playing around with the Code: i am after doing this which works to a point, The problem i am facing it is not reading the whole datetime.csv if i chage something in one file i am getting this 
It is not giving me test1 within the temp.csv

FileName,ModificationDate
/home/usr/Desktop/test23,2016-11-12 11:22:07.410170
FileName,ModificationDate
/home/usr/Desktop/test23,2016-11-12 11:22:07.410170
FileName,ModificationDate
/home/usr/Desktop/test23,2016-11-12 11:22:07.410170

```
def Direcotry_function(directory_dest):
    global directory_path #call the Global Variable
    directory_path =  os.getcwd() # getting Current Directory
    if len(directory_dest) > 1:
        directory_path = directory_dest
    for list in filepath_list:
        Originalfiles = ''.join(list)#Convert to Str
        drive, path = os.path.splitdrive(Originalfiles)#Get the Path
        path, filename = os.path.split(path)#Split the path and filename
        makedir = path + '/' + filename
        Originalfiles_Timestamp = os.path.getmtime(Originalfiles)#Get the Timestamp of File in seconds
        mTime = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(Originalfiles_Timestamp)#Get the Date time in Month Yearformat
        print(mTime)
        print(filename)
        if os.path.exists(os.path.join(directory_path, filename[:]+".copy")):#Check if the FIle exists
            file_csv = csv.DictReader(open('datetime.csv'))#open CSV FILE
            for row in file_csv:#Loop over
                if row['FileName'] == Originalfiles:
                    rowTime =  datetime.datetime.strptime(row['ModificationDate'], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f") #Convert row to DateTime
                    if rowTime == mTime: #Check if Time inside CSV equals mTime
                        print("same")
                    else:
                        with open('datetime.csv', "r") as f:
                            reader = csv.DictReader(f)
                            fieldnames = ['FileName', 'ModificationDate']  # Create Dict Keys
                            for row in reader:
                                with open("temp.csv", 'w') as g:
                                    writer = csv.DictWriter(g, fieldnames=fieldnames)
                                    writer.writeheader()
                                    writer.writerow({"FileName": Originalfiles, "ModificationDate": mTime})
                            #shutil.move("temp.csv", 'datetime.csv')
                        os.system('cp -rv ' + makedir + ' ' + directory_path + '/' + filename[:] + ".copy")
        else:
            #If Copy File Does not Exists in the Folder do the Following:
            os.system('cp -r ' + makedir + ' ' + directory_path + '/' + filename[:]+".copy")#Copy ther File to the Directory
            with open('datetime.csv', 'a') as csvfile:#Open CSV File
                fieldnames = ['FileName', 'ModificationDate']#Create Dict Keys
                writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
                writer.writeheader()
                writer.writerow({'FileName': Originalfiles, 'ModificationDate': mTime})#Write to The CSV File
```

Answer (score 0):

The `rb` mode should only be used on binary files. For text files, just use `r`.

Comment: When i use 'r', I'm getting ` line 135, in Direcotry_function
    writer.writeheader()`

Comment: if i take out tthe writeheader i am getting the following,  line 136, in Direcotry_function
    writer.writerow({"FileName":Originalfiles, "ModificationDate": mTime})